# CakePHP multiple scriptBlock JavaScript code must come in one single HTML <script> Tag

Tags: cakephp, helper, cakephp-3.8

I have multiple scriptBlock in my code which is coming from different pages, but it should create one single `<script>` tag for all JavaScripts written in CakePHP scriptBlock.

My below example code is creating separate `<script>` Tags for each.

```php
echo $this->Html->scriptBlock(
    'jQuery(".investment-table tbody>tr").show()',
    ['block' => true]
);

echo $this->Html->scriptBlock(
    'jQuery(".investment-table tbody>tr").hide()',
    ['block' => true]
);

echo $this->Html->scriptBlock(
    'jQuery(".investment-table tbody>tr").remove()',
    ['block' => true]
);
```

Please suggest a proper method to achieve this from many pages.

Answer (score 1):

`HtmlHelper::scriptBlock()` is by default ment to create a single `<script>` element for each call.

It shouldn't really be a problem though, as:

```html
<script>jQuery(".investment-table tbody>tr").show()</script>
<script>jQuery(".investment-table tbody>tr").hide()</script>
<script>jQuery(".investment-table tbody>tr").remove()</script>
```

and

```html
<script>
jQuery(".investment-table tbody>tr").show()
jQuery(".investment-table tbody>tr").hide()
jQuery(".investment-table tbody>tr").remove()
</script>
```

are functionally identical.

However, for the sake of the argument, if you for whatever reason needed things to into the same element, you could for example write to a custom block, and then output that custom block in a script block, something along the lines of this:

```php
$this->append(
    'mergedScripts',
    'jQuery(".investment-table tbody>tr").show();'
);
```

```php
$this->append(
    'mergedScripts',
    'jQuery(".investment-table tbody>tr").remove();'
);
```

```php
$this->append(
    'mergedScripts',
    'jQuery(".investment-table tbody>tr").remove();'
);
```

```php
echo $this->Html->scriptBlock($this->fetch('mergedScripts'));
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Views > Using View Blocks](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views.html#using-view-blocks)**